# where filter between 2 date columns in snowflake sas

Tags: sql, sas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The problem is I'm trying to pull in a trdate that is 4 days after the s_date

I'm using sas and created a temp table for a snowflake connection labeled column A. I'm joining a table column b. I have my code as follows

```
create table post_date as select * from connection to snf(
select distinct
 A.*
, b. PA
, b. tc
, b. trdate
from stemptable as A
    left join table B
        on A.rp=b.PA
where a.s_date between b.trdate and
```

I know something has to be +4 on b.trdate but unsure of the correct syntax.

This is where I'm stuck. I'm trying to pull in b.trdate to be 4 days after a.s_date. any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using  the DATEADD function in snowflake,   , something like this select DATEADD(Day ,4, date_col ) as future_days. Check this link for more information   https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html

Comment: so this one just adds 4 to column B for example. What I'm looking for is the column B date to be 4 days after the column A date. column A has dates for transactions and column b has separate transactions. thanks again.

Comment: For example if the date in A is jan202022 I need the query to pull the row from column B if it has a date of jan242022

Comment: Why the `DISTINCT`? If you really need this, this may indicate a problem with your data (redundancy). And do you really want an outer join or are you really looking for an inner join? Comparing b values in the where clause would probably turn the join into an inner join anyway, if you don't consider the values being null in an outer joined row.

Comment: to be honest I'm still new to this. I was going off of another query I had that was similar. Thank you for the feedback.. Your query worked.  What if I wanted to pull any date within the 4 days. going from my previous example if the date is available any dates from Jan20 - jan24.

Comment: You mean you want the trdate to be between s_date and s_date  + 4 days? I suppose you can guess the syntax by now. You can use  `BETWEEN` or two comparisons with `AND`.

Comment: I'm still new to sql and programming in general. yes I must not understand the order to put it in. I had BETWEEN before and i'd receive an error. I'm trying again using the code you provided and still receive an error. please see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the trdate to be 4 days after s_date, you want trdate = s_date + 4 days. In SQL the four days are an interval added to the date as in the following query:

```
select
   s.*
 , b.pa
 , b.tc
 , b.trdate
from stemptable as s
left join table tr on tr.pa = s.rp
                  and tr.trdate = s.s_date + interval '4 days';
```

Comment: I tried substituting interval for between like so

and tr.trdate = s.s_date + between '4 days';
error I receive is unexpected 'ON'
and I tried putting it in the where statement like so:
where tr.trdate = s.s_date + between ' 4 days'
this one the error I receive is unexpected 'between'

Comment: You want the trdate to be between s_date and s_date + 4 days, this translates almost word for word to `tr.trdate BETWEEN s.s_date AND s_date + interval '4 days'`. It should not be necessary for you to ask this here. Just read the online documentation, when you have problems with the syntax: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/between.html (And you must of course replace the word `table` in `left join table tr on` with your real table name in the query. I just copied and pasted it thus from your query.)

Comment: And here ist the syntax without `BETWEEN`. It is just combining conditions with `AND` as we are already doing in the `ON` clause. `tr.trdate >= s.s_date AND tr.trdate <= s_date + interval '4 days'`. This is something you should have been able to work out yourself, too, because there is no syntax here that we haven't already used.

Comment: If I would've been able to figure it out on my own I wouldn't have posed the question. I've seen a lot easier questions on this forum than what I asked. But thank you for the clarification.